# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

Unlike the Open Source ads on Meta Stack Overflow, there is no requirement for the Programmers Community Ads to be a coding project of your own.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2635).

Comment: Can you give us an idea what *shouldn't* be proposed?  For example, are personal blogs, sites in which we have a pecuniary interest, or programming-related web comics okay?  Should we try to limit it to sites that would be on-topic in a typical answer?  Or is it more, "propose anything programmers might find interesting but if we don't like it, it will be voted down."

Comment: @Karl What does the *community* want to see? Remember, this is a small ad going on the right side that all visitors will see. So you ideally want something that is of interest to your community that you'd want people to be seeing. It can include events as well as static places that will always be there. It's up to y'all in your voting to decide what is most appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Visit Our Blog]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: What's the name of the font used in this image?

Comment: @StuperUser It's called [Arista Regular](http://www.zetafonts.com/collection/183)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Donate to a fellow Mogrammer!]

Comment: icky pixel artifacts on that stache

Comment: Yeah, not fond of the bottom font either. Will sort out a better image. Do you know the name of that font at the top?

Comment: I'm on board with the Movember cause, but this ad feels weird. I think it'd make more sense if there was a ProgSE *team* registered as opposed to linking just to your individual page. Not that it matters far as donations are concerned, but still... something to try organizing next year, perhaps? :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I know what you mean, I did feel a little like a charlatan and was planning to the link to something more appropriate. I think setting up a team for next year is a great idea.

Comment: @AnnaLear Link updated to the general donation page for great justice.

Comment: @StuperUser The link for the "general donation" button is broken, it points to `http://www.movember.com/donate/payment/member_id/99/` and gets into a redirect loop. Can you nag them about it?

Comment: @Yannis Will do, I was worried about this. From within the UK, he .com redirects to the .co.uk general donation page. I'll change the link to the main page rather than donation. If people want to donate, they'll be willing to find the right page on the appropriate site if they're redirected.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Crazy on tap]

Comment: Crazy on tap is a Community of IT professionals. Where we discuss a wide range of topics. (Not strictly limited IT.) It's an Open, Free anonymous forum. Many things that are off topic here can be discussed there.

Comment: Joel S. Discuss COT is the last SO Pod Cast. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/se-podcast-30-robert-cartaino-rebecca-chernoff/

Answer (score -1):

[image: netsniff-ng - the packet sniffing beast]