# Changing an Ad that has been approved by Voters

Tags: support

Last week I posted an [AD](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2012/3905#3905) for [our Blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/) and it received the 6 votes needed to run.

This was a generic AD, now I am thinking that it would be a good idea to change the AD every time we have a new Blog posting mentioning the Post Name.

**Is it ok to change the AD after it has been voted on?**

**Would it be better to create a new Template AD and put a comment that the Text will change regularly?** (Creating a new ad for every post seems like abuse even if we could get the votes)

**Lastly, assuming this was allowed, would it work?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally changing *specifically* the community blog ad picture, I think, is okay. I highly doubt the community would loudly oppose keeping the Blog ad with a fresher image (unless you changed it to a terrible, terrible image, so you would be wise to just do an overview pass of the image before you change it). The ads now run for a whole year, so getting a new image isn't a bad idea now and then. In this very specific case, I think it's alright.

Changing it for every blog post, however, seems a bit overkill. This mostly comes from the fact we do not support the ability to run "programmatic" ads that update themselves (like our cross-site question ads) - we can only serve static images. Note that I don't think that this classifies as subverting the static image requirement.

In a sense, it is "making this kind of thing work with what we have available", but I think it has the potential to permit a lot more behavior of "repeatedly editing ads every couple of weeks". A fresh image is fine every now and then, but every couple of weeks is pushing it, especially when allowances are already being made. Also hard to justify letting this be a "pseudo-programmatic ad" and not letting others run "pseudo-programmatic ads" for free reign to change the details on the ad at any time - coming up with appropriate restrictions on this seems like it'd make the entire ad system a lot more complex than it truly needs to be.

---

On the topic of blog article visibility though, we did increase the amount of days they show up on the Community Bulletin. Small steps for now in that direction.

Comment: The amount of days blog posts show up on the Community Bulletin was [already increased](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3919/25936) to a week, do you mean more than that?

Comment: @Yannis That is what I did mean, but I misread the printing of the last blog post so I thought it had expired early, so I wasn't positive it was in place yet. Hum.

Comment: Grace, Thank you.. Just to confirm, editing the meta answer will in fact change the Ad that is published, Correct?

Comment: @Morons Yes. I can't say it'll immediately change but it will definitely change.