# Would promoting a charity (Mogrammers) appropriate on the site?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I imagine not, but would it be appropriate for the site to be rebranded for a month or a notice put out to promote the international Men's Health Charity movement [Movember](http://www.movember.com)?

Comment: What happened to your face??? ;P

Comment: That was my effort for Movember 2 years ago, I grew it from November 1st until the next April. It was good to play with while pondering problems.

Comment: One crazy idea that probably wouldn't work is to write a blog post for our [Community Blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/). It should be something about programmers and mustaches though, can't really be only about promoting the charity. Something about [this guy](http://www.boiledbeans.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/e3dd3481c9a351936ed11ba6cef0a873.jpg) perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to do it as a [community promotion ad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2012). The guidelines for a community ad on programmers are fairly open, you just have to convince enough people that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I fully support the Mo-vember cause, so have some sympathy with the suggestion.

However, charity support is a very personal matter, and I would be against any in-your-face adoption of any charity by this site (or any other SE site)

So my answer to your question is a resounding No.

But I like the Community Ad idea

Answer (score 2):

Based on @freiheit's suggestion, I've added a [community ad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5181/12436) you can vote for.

At the moment, the link is to my donation page, leave a comment if you think a different URL would be more aposite.